# React.JS + PIXI -- unable to attach WebGLRenderer to DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pixi.js

Here's some of my React.JS code:

```
  componentDidMount: function componentDidMount() {
    var width = this.props.appWidth;
    var height = this.props.appHeight;
    this._renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(width, height, {
      transparent: true,
      resolution: window.devicePixelRatio,
      antialias: true,
      view: React.findDOMNode(this)
    });
  },
```

I'm getting an error when I try to instantiate this PIXI.WebGLRenderer, because of the following:

[image]

[image]

How do I appropriately add the view to the DOM so that my WebGLRenderer can actually render objects on the screen?

Comment: is _this_ ==a <canvas> tag?